# PHP triggering a background process with nohup equiv

Tags: php, windows

I've been looking through the various discussions and articles on how to have PHP run a process in the background using the **Windows equivalent of nohup**; my code needs to work with both Unix and Windows, but I'm focused on Windows for the moment.

My problem is that all the examples out there in seem to suggest using *exec* or *pclose/popen* or *system*, but when I try them out I see the background process running when called but it seems to hold up the caller until it has finished...

...what I am looking for is the caller to finish quickly whilst the background process continues with what it needs to do (in this case a few seconds of processing, but it could be several minutes in the final version).

I've included a sample program that if you vary $option [found at the bottom of the script] to be set to 210, 220, 230 or 240 then you can see the results. Look in the full results in the log file set by $this->logfn.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

class Test  {
    var $logfn="C:/test.log";
    // ------------------------------------------------
    public function doTrace(string $msgTx) {
        $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', gmdate(time()));
        error_log($now."::".$msgTx."\n", 3, $this->logfn);
        echo "<LI>$now:$msgTx";
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------
    public function doTest(int $option, array $args = null) {
        $this->doTrace("0 ".php_sapi_name());

        if ( strcmp(php_sapi_name(), "cli") == 0 ) {
            // Command line execution
            if ( isset($args) and count($args) > 0 ) $x = $args[1];
            else $x="-";
            $this->doTrace("   900---------------- background cli starting ($x)");
            sleep(1);
            $this->doTrace("   901---------------- tick");
            sleep(1);
            $this->doTrace("   902---------------- tick");
            sleep(1);
            $this->doTrace("   903---------------- tick");
            sleep(1);
            $this->doTrace("   904---------------- tick");
            sleep(1);
            $this->doTrace("   905---------------- tick");
            $this->doTrace("   910 background sleep complete");

        }
        else {
            // Web execution
            unlink($this->logfn);
            $this->doTrace("100---------------- www starting option $option - " . __FILE__);

            $script = __FILE__;

            if ( !file_exists($script) ) echo "<LI>$script NOT FOUND</LI>";

            $php = "php ";
            $cmd = "-f $script ARG1";


            $this->doTrace("200 Starting background process...");
            switch($option){
            case 210:$this->execInBackground210($php, $cmd); break;
            case 220:$this->execInBackground220($php, $cmd); break;
            case 230:$this->execInBackground230($php, $cmd); break;
            case 240:$this->execInBackground240($php, $cmd); break;
            }
            $this->doTrace("300 cmd ran in background");
        }
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------
    // exec
    public function execInBackground210($php, $cmd) {
        if ( substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows" ) {
            $this->doTrace("210a - Spawning $php $cmd");
            exec("start /B $php $cmd", $output, $return);
            echo "<HR>\n\n";
            echo "<UL>";
            echo "<LI>o:" . nl2br(print_r($output, true)) . "</LI>";
            echo "<LI>r:$return</LI>";
            echo "</UL>";
            $this->doTrace("210b - Spawn finished");
        }
        else {
            exec("nohup $cmd > /dev/null &");
        }
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------
    // popen
    public function execInBackground220($php, $cmd) {
        if ( substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows" ) {
            echo "<LI>$cmd";
            $this->doTrace("220a - Spawning $php $cmd");
            pclose(popen("start /B " . "$php $cmd", "r"));
            $this->doTrace("220b - Spawn finished");
        }
        else {
            exec("$php $cmd" . " > /dev/null &");
        }
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // COM/run
    public function execInBackground230($php, $cmd) {
        if ( substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows" ) {
            $this->doTrace("230a - Spawning $php $cmd");
            $shell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
            $shell->run("$php $cmd", 0, false);
            $this->doTrace("230b - Spawn finished");
        }
        else {
            exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
        }
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // system
    public function execInBackground240($php, $cmd) {
        if ( substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows" ) {
            $this->doTrace("240a - Spawning $php $cmd");
            system("start /B $php $cmd"." 2>&1", $return);
            $this->doTrace("240b - Spawn done [$return]");
        }
        else {
            exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
        }
    }
}

//$option=210;
//$option=220;
//$option=230;
$option=240;

$try = new Test();
echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
if ( isset($argv) ) {
    echo $try->doTest($option,$argv);
}
else {
    echo $try->doTest($option,null);
}
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

I'm hoping to see in the log file that the 900 series logs run after the others (from the webpage calls) have completed, but what I see is the the webpage waits for the background process to complete before control is passed back to the front end - resulting in the 900 series logs sitting in the middle of the log file rather than the end.

The log file currently reads as follows (when running $option=240)

```
2019-03-31 16:53:37::100---------------- www starting option 240 - C:\.....testSpawn.php
2019-03-31 16:53:37::200 Starting background process...
2019-03-31 16:53:37::240a - Spawning php  -f C:\.... testSpawn.php ARG1
2019-03-31 16:53:37::0 cli
2019-03-31 16:53:37::   900---------------- background cli starting (ARG1)
2019-03-31 16:53:38::   901---------------- tick
2019-03-31 16:53:39::   902---------------- tick
2019-03-31 16:53:40::   903---------------- tick
2019-03-31 16:53:42::   904---------------- tick
2019-03-31 16:53:43::   905---------------- tick
2019-03-31 16:53:43::   910 background sleep complete
2019-03-31 16:53:43::240b - Spawn done [0]
2019-03-31 16:53:43::300 cmd ran in background
```

So what is it that needs to be done to make a Windows PHP environment to run spawned processes in the background asynchronously?

(I'm on PHP5.7)

Answer (score 1):

`start /B` is fine. However, usually `php` is not in the `%PATH%` on Windows. You should determine the full path. Try the `PHP_BINARY` constant which should contain the absolute path to the PHP executable.

When you want to read the `stdout` stream of the process, you can make it non-blocking:

```
$cmd = PHP_BINARY;
if(is_resource($proc = proc_open("start /B $cmd script.php", [['pipe', 'r'], ['pipe', 'w'], ['pipe', 'w']], $pipes)))
{
  echo '<h1>Process Stream</h1>', PHP_EOL;
  stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], false);
  stream_set_blocking($pipes[2], false);
```

Then you can access the streams without waiting for `EOF`/`EOL`.

Comment: Thanks Quasi, I have added a version of this suggestion as an execInBackground250, and indeed it does seem to be closer to what I'm looking for, but I notice that the background 900 messages stop if the caller stops - i.e. it seems that the background dies if the caller dies - which is not fulfilling the nohup requirement as I want the web front end to continue with other things while the background runs.